# How to create the bookmark of the iframe content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

In this i got a list element with id "about_ma" and a iframe with name "page" which is initialy not displayed.

```
<div id="navigation">
          <ul id="nav">
      <li id="about_ma"><a href="index1.php?name=about.php">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="index1.php?name=director.php">Director Desk</a></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
 <iframe src="<?php echo $name;?>"style="display:none;"name="page" id="nav_content">
 </iframe>
```

I am using the following php code on to get the name in url

```
   <?php
   $name= $_GET['name'];
   echo "<br>";
   echo $name;
   ?>`
```

Script i am using is

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#about_ma').click(function(){
           $('#nav_content').fadeIn();
  });
  });
```

If my concept is correct then according to me when i click on About Us the iframe with src about.php should get displayed.The whole coding is done on index1.php.
So can anyone tell me the error in this because i tried this and its not working.The major aim before this coding is to create a book mark of the iframe content.If my concept is wrong so can any one tell me how can i create a bookmark of the iframe content.Because when u refresh the whole webpage the iframe with default src is loaded and due to this the bookmarking of he iframe content is not possible.
plz help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `src` of iframe to change when clicking a nav link you need to modify it with `attr()` method. In order to be able to bookmark you will need to use hashes. Will store a hash name in `data-` attribute of link.

HTML

```
<li id="about_ma"><a href="index1.php?name=about.php" data-hash="about">About Us</a></li>
```

JS

```
$('#navigation a').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();/* prevent browser opening link*/
       location.hash=$(this).data('hash');/* set hash of url*/
       var newSrc=$(this).attr('href');
       $('#nav_content').attr('src', newSrc).fadeIn(); 

    });

/* on page load*/

var hash=location.hash;
if(hash && hash !='#'){
  hash=hash.slice(1)
  $('#navigation a[data-hash='+hash+']').click()
}
```

Comment: updated solution to use hashes. If you want back button capability, will need to implement `hashchange` capability. Suggest using plugin like `history.js` or `jQuery BBQ`